# Different scaling on different monitors

Tags: 20.04

I'm total newbie so please bear with me. I've this thinkpad w540 with resolution of 2880 X 1620 pixels and external monitor with 1280 X 1024 resolution. Currently I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with Gnome 3.36.9 and I've made scale to 200% in laptop so that everything fits nicely. But when I connect with external monitor it scales to 200% too. Is there any simple fix to this problem? Yeah, I saw other posts regarding this but didn't find any good examples that solved this issue. Most of them were either switch to wayland(can't because of nvidia) or some other xrandr trickery which involved making the resolution lower.

Comment: Sorry, it's 20.04.3 LTS and the kernel is 5.11.0-44-generic.

Comment: How exactly have you made scale to 200%?

Comment: By going to settings -> displays -> scale.

Comment: Do you have 2 video cards? Just tested with 2 monitors attached to single gpu and obtained desired result using Fractional Scale setting for each monitor individually. Have 20.04.3 LTS Desktop as well.

Comment: Yeah I do have 2 video cards.

Answer (score 2):

If you activate the last option, fractional scaling, it lets you to change the scale independently from each monitor and also have scales different than a hole number.

Note that it can perform badly and in same cases it could not function as it must (but that should be another question).

[image: Screen capture in spanish of the fractional scaling configuration windows]